# Rails 4 syntax error with action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

All of a sudden, my mailer just broke. It is a simple form that sends a request email to an admin. I keep getting strange syntax errors. Maybe someone could help me please!

RequestMailer.rb

```
  class RequestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "no-reply@bethelmusic.org"

     def request_submit(request_form)
     @request_form = request_form
     mail :to => (AdminUser.select(:email).map(&:email), :subject => "New design request")
   end
 end
```

Request_submit.html.erb

```
 <h3>
  Name: <%= @request_form[:Name] %></br>

  Email: <%= @request_form[:Email] %></br>

  Project: <%= @request_form[:Project] %></br>

  Description: <%= @request_form[:Description] %></br>

  Dimensions: <%= @request_form[:Dimensions] %></br>

  References: <%= @request_form[:design_file] %></br>

  Due Date: <%= @request_form[:Due_Date] %></br>

  Dropbox Link: <%= @request_form[:Link] %></br>

  Comments: <%= @request_form[:Comments] %></br>
</h3>
```

Request Forms controller

```
def create
 @request_form = RequestForm.new(request_form_params)

 respond_to do |format|
  if @request_form.save
    RequestMailer.request_submit(@request_form).deliver  <-- #HERE IS WHERE THE "ERROR" IS
    format.html { render partial: "success" }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @request_form }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @request_form.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
 end
end
```

So the error I am getting is " syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' " 
I do not have a ',' there and there is no need why it should be asking for a close paren.

Thoughts and help please! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
:to => (AdminUser.select(:email).map(&:email), :subject => "New design request")
```

The value of `options[:to]` doesn't look like a hash at all. It is not a valid syntax, unless prepended by a method name, which is not the case. Should probably be this:

```
:to => AdminUser.select(:email).map(&:email), :subject => "New design request"
```

But if you insist on surrounding it with braces, do so:

```
{:to => AdminUser.select(:email).map(&:email), :subject => "New design request"}
```